# angular 2 spring authentication

Tags: angular, authentication, angular2-services

I try to do authentication by angular 2. In BackEnd Spring Security.
Authentication and logout is work success, but when i using canActive Guard for guard route, i can not change boolean variable status.
Please tell me , what i wrong.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http,Headers,Response,URLSearchParams} from '@angular/http';
import {User} from "./User";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class HttpService{
private loggedIn = false;


  constructor(private http: Http){
 }

 getData(){return this.http.get('/test')}

 postData(User){
   let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-
 urlencoded' });
 var params = new URLSearchParams();
 params.set('username',User.username);
 params.set('password',User.password);

 return this.http.post('/login', params.toString(), { headers: headers })
  .map(res => res.json())
  .map((res)=>{
    if(res.status == 200)
      {
          this.loggedIn = true
      }
      return res.success;
  })
  .catch((error:any) =>{return Observable.throw(error);});;
}

  isLoggedIn() {
    return this.loggedIn;
  }

  logout() {
    this.loggedIn = false;
 }

 }

import {Inject, Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {CanActivate} from "@angular/router";
import {HttpService} from "./http.service";

 @Injectable()
  export class CanActivateViaAuthGuard implements CanActivate{

 constructor(@Inject(HttpService) private httpService: HttpService){}

 canActivate(){return this.httpService.isLoggedIn();
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you using isAuthenticated() spring security method in canActive Guard?

Comment: No? i check  http status code.

Comment: can you post your canActive guard code

Comment: in code above...export class CanActivateViaAuthGuard implements CanActivate{

Comment: what is your CanActivate checking to determine if the user is logged in or not?

Comment: if logged success http status 200 else 401. response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK ) and  response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);

Comment: if you can post the canActivate code i can help